# AWS cognito nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am working in a project in which the authentication is managed by AWS cognito. I have implemented google authentication with cognito. I was successful to get google auth token and pass it to the backend. I created an identity pool in aws. Now, i want to return the aws session token back to the UI from backend. So far I managed to write  the code,

```
function login(token){
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'myidpoolid',
    Logins: {
      "accounts.google.com": token,
    },
    });
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
    // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
    var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
    var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
    var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
   });
return AWS.config.credentials;
}

let credentials = login(google_token);
>>>>>Here credentials is empty

return JSON.stringify({'Message':"Sample message",'data':credentials})
```

But I am not able to return this credentials to where i call the login method. I get only an empty result. I am a newbie to nodejs.Please help

Comment: You didn't show how you return to UI?

Comment: `AWS.config.credentials.get()` is an async call. Wrap your helper in a promise or pass a callback to get the value.

Comment: still i am not able to create a user in userpool with AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials

Comment: You wouldn't expect it to create a user in a user pool. `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` uses a federated identity (identity pool)